# combine SQLAlchemy Core and ORM get problems

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy, relational-database

How do I combine the two component of SQLAlchemy -- Core (SQL Expression) and ORM ?
I have some table that using ORM mapper and others just Table object, and I want **one connection and one transaction for the two**.

I have following two examples but run into problems (result is not consistent to my queries that interleaving two access styles).
One using autocommit session, another using default session.

---

```
session_autocommit=Session(bind=db,autocommit=True)
def f():
    with session_autocommit.begin() as trans:
        # ORM 
        x=session_autocommit.query(Mytable).filter(Mytable.id==1).first()
        # sql expression by SQLAlchemy Core 
        session_autocommit.execute(mytable.update().where(mytable.c.id==1)\
            .values(note=None)) 
        # update via ORM
        x.note='a'
f() # ok two update appear in log.
f() # ! only one update as below

x.note == 'a'
# the second run of f() returns False but should be True.
```

the log of second run of f()  says it only one update (note=None) , the second update is missed?

```
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT mytable.id AS mytable_id, mytable.note AS mytable_note
FROM mytable 
WHERE mytable.id = %(id_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'param_1': 1, 'id_1': 1}
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE mytable SET note=%(note)s WHERE mytable.id = %(id_1)s
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'id_1': 1, 'note': None}
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

---

**UPDATE** The second problem is solved.
Thanks @univerio 's comment, I need to `flush` it first for right ordering of executions. Since I am using two independent mechanism of SQLAlchemy.

```
session=Session(bind=db,autocommit=False)
# default session must rely commit to control transaction.

session.commit()
x=session.query(Mytable).filter(Mytable.id==1).first()
x.note='a'
session.execute(mytable.update().where(mytable.c.id==1)\
    .values(note=None)) 
session.commit()

x.note=='a'
# the test return True but should be None.
```

the log says the different order of two updates ?

```
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT mytable.id AS mytable_id, mytable.note AS mytable_note
FROM mytable 
WHERE mytable.id = %(id_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'id_1': 1, 'param_1': 1}
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE mytable SET note=%(note)s WHERE mytable.id = %(id_1)s
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'note': None, 'id_1': 1}
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT mytable.id AS mytable_id
FROM mytable 
WHERE mytable.id = %(param_1)s
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'param_1': 1}
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE mytable SET note=%(note)s WHERE mytable.id = %(mytable_id)s
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'note': 'a', 'mytable_id': 1}
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your first case. The second case is expected because the flush occurs with the commit; if you do `session.flush()` after `x.note = 'a'` you'll get the result you expected.

Comment: thanks @univerio , edited, the problem in first case is happened after second repeat run.

Answer (score 0):

After reading more about `session`, I have answer about it.

---

`session` has its working mechanisms, one is `unit of work` --

> "All changes to objects maintained by a Session are tracked - before
>   the database is queried again or before the current transaction is
>   committed, it flushes all pending changes to the database. This is
>   known as the Unit of Work pattern."
>   http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html

- The first problem is because of `unit of work` so that SQLAlchemy will track what is changed and smartly do only what's really needed. The result is only one update is needed.
- The second problem is solved by manual `session.flush()` the ORM update to get the right ordering of executions. Since I am using two independent mechanism of SQLAlchemy and it seems that `unit of work` doesn't also apply to raw SQL expression.